# Why are my component library styles rendering twice in Next.js?

Tags: next.js

My project is using a component library that requires a `<Theme>` component to wrap all of the other components. I'm using the Next.js app router and I figured the best place to put the component is in the root layout file.

However, doing that results in the component styles being rendered twice, once in `layout.css` and then again in `page.css`.

The `<Theme>` is only instantiated once in the root layout, while the pages make use of the components like `<Button>` and `<Input>`.

```js
import { Theme } from 'component-library';

export default function RootLayout({
  children,
}: {
  children: React.ReactNode;
}) {
  return (
    <html lang='en'>
      <body>
        <Theme>{children}</Theme>
      </body>
    </html>
  );
}
```

If I move `<Theme>` into each page individually, the styles are only rendered once in `page.css`, but I was hoping I could instantiate it in a single place.

I know I could create a HOC to instantiate it but that too would need to be added to each page, so there's not much difference.

Why is this happening? Is this specific to the root layout, or would this happen in nested layouts as well? Where should this `<Theme>` component be instantiated so all pages inherit it?

Answer (score 1):

The React Strict Mode causes this!

https://react.dev/blog/2022/03/29/react-v18#new-strict-mode-behaviors

You can disable it in `next.config.json` file:

```
module.exports = {
    reactStrictMode: false,
}
```

Comment: That's what I thought, but that didn't work. Keep in mind it's not just rendering twice. The component styles are actually in two different files - `layout.css` and `page.css`.

Comment: After a bit of searching in Nextjs discussions, I found this thread which according to this is a newly identified issue and not fixed yet.
https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/49115